# A simple counting code which i dont understand how it work

Tags: count, python-3.6

```
words = "Fine and Cloudy"
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
my_words = [words.index(c) for c in words if c not in vowels and words.count(c) == 1]
print(my_words)
```

I'm just don't understand why the output is `[0, 9, 10, 14]` and how does this simple code works?
Can somebody explain in detail? Please!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints the position of those letters in the string "Fine and Cloudy" that are not vowels and that occur exactly once. Those are the "F" (position 0), "C" (position 9), "l" (position 10), and the "y" (position 14).

Comment: Now I totally get it. Thank you so much!